# Cryptography cesar algorithm

Tags: java, cryptography

Hi i'm developing a cesar algorithm app it doesn't contain errors but i have a problem with special character i have squares instead of the appropriate character also i don't know how to deal with the spaces in my code

```
 package cesar;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cesar {

private static short codeMajuscule=65;
private static short codeMinuscule=97;
private static short tailleAlph = 26;

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Entrer la chaine a crypter");
    String phrase = sc.next();
      System.out.println("entrer votre cle");
   int c= sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println( "la phrase après transformation " + chiffrement(          phrase , c ) );     
}

private static String chiffrement( String ch , int n ){      

    String chDecripte="";
            ch=ch.replaceAll("[éèêë]", "e");
            ch=ch.replaceAll("[Ç]", "C");
            ch=ch.replaceAll("[ÈÉÊË]", "E");
            ch=ch.replaceAll("[ÌÍÎÏ]", "I");
            ch=ch.replaceAll("Ñ", "N");
            ch=ch.replaceAll("ÒÓÔŒ", "O");
            ch=ch.replaceAll("ÙÚÛÜ", "U");
            ch=ch.replaceAll("ÝŸ", "Y");
            ch=ch.replaceAll("àáâæ", "a");          
            ch=ch.replaceAll("[ÀÁÂÆ]", "A");
            ch=ch.replaceAll("[èéêë]", "e");                      
            ch=ch.replaceAll("[ìíîï]", "i");
            ch=ch.replaceAll("[ñ]", "n");
            ch=ch.replaceAll("[òóôœ]", "o");
            ch=ch.replaceAll("[ùúûü]", "u");
            ch=ch.replaceAll("[ýÿ]", "y");

    for( int i = 0 ; i < ch.length() ; i++ ){
        if( ch.codePointAt(i) >= codeMajuscule && 
                ch.codePointAt(i) <= ( codeMajuscule + tailleAlph ) ){

            chDecripte += (char) ( ( ch.codePointAt( i ) - codeMajuscule + n ) %  tailleAlph +  codeMajuscule ) ;

        }else if( ch.codePointAt(i) >= codeMinuscule && 
                ch.codePointAt(i) <= ( codeMinuscule + tailleAlph ) ){

            chDecripte += (char) ( ( ch.codePointAt( i ) - codeMinuscule + n ) %  tailleAlph +  codeMinuscule ) ;    
        }else{
            chDecripte += ch.charAt( i );
        }
    }
    return chDecripte;  
}   
}
```

and thanks

Comment: Can you give an example input and output that shows your problem?

Comment: for exemple when i write élève or something like that i have empty squares in the place of the specil caracter that i want to decode also when i write something with a space i have error because the case of the space isn't treated in my code

Comment: This may be the reason for your space error, but you're not consuming the newline delimeter. Replace `sc.next();` with `sc.nextLine()` so this will consume the entire line of input. `next()` only consumes input until the next space.

Answer (score 0):

Usually (not always) Cesar ciphers do not account for space characters, they ignore any white space and special characters such as periods, colons, commas etc. If you choose to allow for them you'll need to create a "key" or "map" so you know how to undo the operation.

Typically all characters can be manipulated using their numerical representation (integer format). If you treat them as numbers this becomes a much simpler problem. Since you are using special characters I assume you are using a UTF-8 format? You might consider operating on the numerical values and use this UTF-8 chart as a "map":

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

If you ever are working with ASCII only subset use this chart as a "map":

http://www.asciitable.com/

Things to consider when doing a Cesar cipher are you normally want to remain within the bounds of the normal alphabet or some specified subset of characters. So when you reach the letter 'z' (122 integer value) if you are shifting right you need to drop back down to 'a' (97 integer value) then continue to shift from there.

For example we know there are 26 numbers in the lowercase alphabet and they range in ASCII from 97 - 122. So you might do a check like (pseudo-code):

```
char char_to_shift; /* the character to be shifted */

if (char_to_shift + shift_amount > 'z') {
    tmp = shift_amount - ('z' - char_to_shift);
    shift_amount = tmp;
    char_to_shift='a';
    char_to_shift+=shift_amount;
} else {
    char_to_shift+=shift_amount;
}
```

So in the above pseudo code let's assume we were shifting a character 5 to the right (ROT-5) and that character was 'x' (120 integer value). We would have shifted to 125 which is the '{' character. Instead we do 'z' (122) - 'x' (120) leaving us with a 2. Then we subtract that from the shift_amount (5) so we're left with 3. Then we reset the char_to_shift to 'a' and shift the remaining amount 3 to end up with a 'c'.

Also keep in mind there are gaps between the Upper case alphabet and the lower case alphabet that need to be accounted for if you decide to allow shifting a lowercase letter to an upper case letter.

To generate your own "map of values" just try printing out the decimal value of each character in your subset of allowed characters if the above tables do not fit what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is not correct:

```
...
}else if( ch.codePointAt(i) >= codeMinuscule && 
        ch.codePointAt(i) <= ( codeMinuscule + tailleAlph ) ){

    chDecripte += (char) ( ( ch.codePointAt( i ) - codeMinuscule + n ) %  tailleAlph +  codeMinuscule ) ;    
}else{
    chDecripte += ch.charAt( i );
}
```

first of all, your input may not be all uppercase characters. But the second if line for some reason suddenly seems to count down instead of up. You should only do that during decryption. Also the if statement uses `<=` and `>=` while the `=` character is obviously already covered by the previous `if`.

And, finally, the last `else` will never be reached because it is covered by the `if` and `else if` statements.

---

I've created an alternate source code with some hints inside:

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cesar {

    // unchanged
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Entrer la chaine a crypter");
        String phrase = sc.next();
        System.out.println("entrer votre cle");
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("la phrase après transformation " + chiffrement(phrase, c));
    }

    // you can directly show what you are doing by using 'A' and 'Z'
    private static int CODE_MAJESCULE = 'A';
    // you may actually not need constants for this
    private static int CODE_MINESCULE = 'Z';
    // the TAILLE_ALPH is of course the difference of those two
    private static int TAILLE_ALPH = CODE_MINESCULE - CODE_MAJESCULE + 1;

    // split out into separate methods whereever possible
    private static String normalise(String phrase) {
        // probably better to change Æ into AE
        // but
        String doublesRemoved = phrase.replaceAll("Æ", "a").replaceAll("Œ", "o");
        doublesRemoved = doublesRemoved.replaceAll("æ", "a").replaceAll("œ", "o");
        // separates character and diacritic (ë becomes e + " in a way)
        String separated = Normalizer.normalize(doublesRemoved, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        // this will also remove all non-western characters
        String accentsRemoved = separated.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
        // and finally, we only seem to handle uppercase
        return accentsRemoved.toUpperCase();
    }

    private static String chiffrement(String phrase, int cle) {

        // first normalize the message so we can handle it
        String phraseNormalise = normalise(phrase);

        // use a StringBuilder (or the right size) for adding characters in loops
        StringBuilder chiffre = new StringBuilder(phraseNormalise.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < phraseNormalise.length(); i++) {
            // codePointAt doesn't play nice with String.length()
            // and it's now all ASCII anyway
            char v = phraseNormalise.charAt(i);

            // --- filter out special characters
            if (v < CODE_MAJESCULE || v > CODE_MINESCULE) {
                chiffre.append(v);
                // most Java programmers use continue for "guards"
                continue;
            }

            char c = cesar(v, cle);

            chiffre.append(c);
        }

        // ... and return
        return chiffre.toString();
    }

    private static char cesar(char v, int cle) {
        // --- convert into element e in [0..TAILLE_ALPH)
        int e = v - CODE_MAJESCULE;

        // --- perform the cesar chiffre
        int cc = (e + cle) % TAILLE_ALPH;

        // --- convert back into A .. Z
        char c = (char) (cc + CODE_MAJESCULE);
        return c;
    }
}
```

most importantly it performs the Caesar cipher itself on a separate line. This makes it much easier to get things right.

Breaking down problems in sub-problems (and testing them separately) is one of the most important skills in programming. Never forget to do so.

Comment: Thanks a lot but now when i enter a special caracter in the result it will be deleted also the space is not treated i have an error when i enter it

Comment: Yes, well, you'll have to decide to either *expand your alphabet* or keep or remove the characters. The other error is already in your own code, just replace `next()` with `nextLine()` as `next()` just reads up to the next white space. The original Caesar cipher just works on a single alphabet containing the usual characters.